# How do I use setTimeOut inside an if ... else statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this simple code here.

```
(function () {
    let i = 1;
    var pgn = 0;
    for (i = 1; pgn <=10; i++) {
        if (i === 1) {
            pgn += 1;
            console.log('Hello')
        }

        else if (i > 1) {
           console.log('Hi');

        }
    }
})();
```

I want to introduce setTimeout into the else block, I mean, I want the else block to be executed exactly after 3 seconds of if block's execution.

This is what I tried:

```
(function () {
    var i;
    var pgn = 0;
    for (i = 1; pgn <=10; i++) {
        if (i === 1) {
            pgn += 1;
            console.log('Hello');
            
        }

        else if (i > 1) {
            
              setTimeout(function () {
             console.log('Hi')
              pgn+=2;
             }, 3000)
    
        }
    }
})();
```

And it gives me this following error on the console

```
      0: ExitFrame [pc: 0000024FB9DDC5C1]
Security context: 0x03781af1e6e9 <JSObject>
    1: /* anonymous */ [0000006D8510C001] [c:\Users\darkcode\Desktop\Spares\js\Projects\test.js:~1] [pc=0000024FB9E71E9A](this=0x03c36da0d481 <JSGlobal Object>)
    2: /* anonymous */ [0000006D8510C041] [c:\Users\darkcode\Desktop\Spares\js\Projects\test.js:19] [bytecode=0000028239256A41 offset=7](this=0x006d8510c171 <Object map = 000000B83C...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF6D00FDD8A v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4506
 2: 00007FF6D00D8886 node::MakeCallback+4534
 3: 00007FF6D00D9200 node_module_register+2032
 4: 00007FF6D03F30DE v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
```

Comment: `else { setTimeout(function(){ /*...*/ }, 3000) }`

Comment: *"I want to introduce setTimeOut into the else block"* - ... And what's stopping you from doing that?  Have you tried anything at all?  What didn't work?

Comment: Yes I did, it gives me a long thick error @David

Comment: For what it's worth, it's `setTimeout()`, not `setTimeOut()`. You'll get errors if you don't use the correct function name. Also, learning to read big fat error messages is worth a lot of your time.

Comment: @DarkDevil: If you can update the question to include code which produces the error and information about the error, such as the error message and the line which produces it and what specifically isn't clear about it, we can help you understand and correct the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, you are encouraged to start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Okay, Okay I know that @David, I thought maybe my code is garbage, so I didn't put it in there. let me update it

Comment: @David, please have a look'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Out of memory" would imply that you probably have an infinite loop that keeps allocating more memory.  And it looks like you have exactly that.  Under no condition in this logic would `pgn` ever be `> 10`, so the loop continues indefinitely.

Each iteration of the loop sets a new timeout, allocating a little more memory, until the application crashes.

Perhaps you meant to use `i` for the terminating condition?:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
```

This would execute the loop 10 times, printing `"Hello"` once and `"Hi"` nine times, as I would expect.

Or perhaps you meant to modify the logic within the loop to modify `pgn` differently?  It's not entirely clear what the intended result is, only that the current problem is an infinite loop.

---

**Edit:** As you're continuing to modify the code while I write this answer, that makes things a little more clear.  Consider this logic:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('Hi')
    pgn+=2;
}, 3000)
```

You're modifying `pgn` *later*, *after* the loop has finished.  (Since `setTimeout` won't execute its function until the thread is available for it.)  Since the loop never finishes, you have a catch-22.  The loop has to finish in order for you to execute the logic that allows it to finish.

Don't modify `pgn` in the `setTimeout`, modify it in the loop:

```
else if (i > 1) {
    pgn+=2;
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Hi');
    }, 3000);
}
```

The result at this point would be one `"Hello"` and, three seconds later, five `"Hi"`s.

Comment: Thanks man, actually I figured it out while you were writing the answer. But I had no idea what's the reason. Thanks for pointing it out. Thanks for your time. Really appreciate it.